# In Django Rest Framework, How to save Foreign Key value in to_internal_value?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Custom Field Ref: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#using-source

Here is my Serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    short_address = AddressField(source='*')
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'order_name', 'short_address',)
```

Custom Address field:

```
class AddressField(serializers.Field):

def to_representation(self, obj):
    ret = {
        "name": obj.address.name,
        "city": obj.address.city
    }
    return ret

def to_internal_value(self, data):
    ret = {
        "address__name": data["name"], // Not Working
        "address__city": data["city"], // Not Working
    }
    return ret
```

I have models as Below

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,)
    address= models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20,)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20,)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20,)
```

Is there any way to directly store foreign key's through `to_internal_value` ?

Comment: You need to create new address? Did you try writable nested serializers? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: I want to update existing address particular field.